# python remove everything between <div class="comment> .. any... </div>

Tags: python, class, html

how do you use python 2.6 to remove everything including the `<div class="comment"> ....remove all ....</div>`

i tried various way using re.sub without any success

Thank you

Comment: obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 18):

This can be done easily and reliably using an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<body><div>1</div><div class="comment"><strong>2</strong></div></body>')
>>> for div in soup.findAll('div', 'comment'):
...   div.extract()
... 
<div class="comment"><strong>2</strong></div>
>>> soup
<body><div>1</div></body>
```

See this question for examples on [why parsing HTML using regular expressions is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege).

Answer (score 3):

With [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html):

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.fromstring(input)
for el in doc.cssselect('div.comment'):
    el.drop_tree()
result = html.tostring(doc)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot properly parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a HTML parser such as [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: i am trying to remove everything including the div and everything in between.  I cant seems to find any reference about that in BeautifulSoup

Comment: another example, say like i want to remove <table> ... </table>, so i am trying to remove all the tables in the html contents, i am not sure how do you do that in BeautifulSoup

Comment: Not even in the "Removing elements" subsection of the "Modifying the Parse Tree" section of the documentation?

Comment: yes, i saw that but you cant remove specific class or id related to that tag

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it is usually a bad idea to process XML with regular expressions. Nevertheless:

```
>>> re.sub('>[^<]*', '>', '<div class="comment> .. any… </div>')
'<div class="comment></div>'
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP wishes to also remove the bookend items of the DIV tag itself in addition to the contents.

Comment: yes, basically , i am trying to remove from the start to the end of the div, 

other example, say like you want to remove certain table within html contents such as remove all <table id="1"> ... </table>,

Answer (score 0):

non regex way

```
pat='<div class="comment">'
for chunks in htmlstring.split("</div>"):
    m=chunks.find(pat)
    if m!=-1:
       chunks=chunks[:m]
    print chunks
```

output

```
$ cat file
one two <tag> ....</tag>
 adsfh asdf <div class="comment"> ....remove
all ....</div>s sdfds
<div class="blah" .......
.....
blah </div>

$ ./python.py
one two <tag> ....</tag>
 adsfh asdf
s sdfds
<div class="blah" .......
.....
blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Beautiful soup and do something like this to get all of those elements, and then just replace inside

```
tomatosoup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)

tomatochunks = tomatosoup.findall("div", {"class":"comment"} )

for chunk in tomatochunks:
   #remove the stuff
```

Comment: also if its XML and not HTML use BeautifulStoneSoup

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html