# Deleting all data between two html tags in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was making a webscraper and i wanted to delete a few divs completely since they are not required for my analysis on the data.
I am using Beautiful Soup to parse the data but i cant figure out how to completely eliminate a div

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649751/python-remove-everything-between-div-class-comment-any-div

Comment: With lxml.html:

from lxml import html
doc = html.fromstring(input)
for el in doc.cssselect('div.comment'):
    el.drop_tree()
result = html.tostring(doc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> blah = '<div id="test"><p>one</p></div><div id="okay"><p>something</p></div>'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(blah)
>>> soup('div', {'id': 'test'})[0].extract()
<div id="test"><p>one</p></div>
>>> soup
<html><body><div id="okay"><p>something</p></div></body></html>
```